# Spring Data JPA (CrudRepository) - BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to use Spring Data JPA - CrudRepository use without any implementation (all default options).

With my code I am having this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springJpaContactService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sample.hibernate.ContactRepository com.sample.hibernate.RepositoryContactServiceImpl.contactRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>       at com.sample.hibernate.HibernateJpaApplication.main(HibernateJpaApplication.java:15)

There are my classes responsible for CrudRepository:

**ContactRepository**:

```
package com.sample.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> {

    List<Contact> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<Contact> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

}
```

**RepositoryContactService**:

```
package com.sample.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

public interface RepositoryContactService {
    List<Contact> findAll();

    List<Contact> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<Contact> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

**RepositoryContactServiceImpl**:

```
package com.sample.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@Service("springJpaContactService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RepositoryContactServiceImpl implements RepositoryContactService {
    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(contactRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Contact> findByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return contactRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Contact> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName,
            String lastName) {
        return contactRepository
                .findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

**Contact**:

```
package com.sample.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="Contact.findAll", query="select c from Contact c"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Contact.findAllWithDetail", query = "select distinct c from Contact c left join fetch c.contactTelDetails t left join fetch c.hobbies h"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Contact.findById", query = "select distinct c from Contact c left join fetch c.contactTelDetails t left join fetch c.hobbies h where c.id = :id") })
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="contactResult", entities=@EntityResult(entityClass=Contact.class)
)
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8008307767408320097L;
    private Long id;
    private int version;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private Set<ContactTelDetail> contactTelDetails = new HashSet<ContactTelDetail>();
    private Set<Hobby> hobbies = new HashSet<Hobby>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<ContactTelDetail> getContactTelDetails() {
        return contactTelDetails;
    }

    public void setContactTelDetails(Set<ContactTelDetail> contactTelDetails) {
        this.contactTelDetails = contactTelDetails;
    }

    public void addContactTelDetail(ContactTelDetail contactTelDetail) {
        contactTelDetail.setContact(this);
        getContactTelDetails().add(contactTelDetail);
    }

    public void removeContactTelDetail(ContactTelDetail contactTelDetail) {
        getContactTelDetails().remove(contactTelDetail);
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "contact_hobby_detail", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "HOBBY_ID"))
    public Set<Hobby> getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(Set<Hobby> hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [id=" + id + ", version=" + version + ", firstName="
                + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", birthDate="
                + birthDate + "]";
    }

}
```

**app-config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sample.hibernate" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.hibernate" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.sample.hibernate"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

I would be glad for any clue.. This example is from a book and I checked 3 times already with it + online tutorials and I have no clue why it is not working as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything with annotations were fine - no need to move @Repository to ContactRepository. This is because ContactRepository extends CrudRepository which tells Spring that he can autowire with reference in RepositoryContactServiceImpl. Problem was in maven configuration (as You were thinking correctly and thanks for that). I changed:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and now repository works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `@Repository` annotation in the wrong place. Your `ContactRepository` class should be the one annotated with `@Repository`.

Spring is failing to autowire your `ContactRepository` because it is not managed by Spring, since you did not annotate it with `@Repository`.

Also, you have `@Transactional` on your `RepositoryContactServiceImpl`, which will make all public methods in that class transactional, so putting `@Transactional` on each of your methods in that class is redundant. If you need each of the methods to have different transactional behavior, you could leave the `@Transactional` annotation on each method, and modify for each method to fit your needs. Then you could remove the `@Transactional` from the class.

However, if each method requires the same type of transaction, as in the example provided, you can remove the `@Transactional` annotation from each method, and leave the `@Transactional` at the class level, and specify your `readOnly` property there.

Comment: I totally agree with You about @Transactional stuff - It was just for testing purpouse.

Comment: I added @Repository to ContactRepository but it still fails (same exception). The implementation of ContactRepository is not needed because it should be served with CrudRepository, am I right? I spend 3h today with fighting this example and I have no clue what is wrong..

Comment: And you removed the `@Repository` from the `RepositoryContactServiceImpl`?

Comment: Correct. RepositoryContactServiceImpl has only @Service("springJpaContactService"). ContactRepository has @Repository and ContactService is without any annotation.

Comment: And you're still getting `BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sample.hibernate.ContactRepository`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that model classes are implemented correct way because all queries (even with table connections) using Hibernate or JPA+Hibernate were working fine (even with Criteria API and it's metamodel).

Comment: Yes - "Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sample.hibernate.ContactRepository com.sample.hibernate.RepositoryContactServiceImpl.contactRepository..."

Comment: How are you building and running? Do you use maven?

Comment: I am using eclipse + maven. Maybe It's because of dependencies.. If You want to You can clone https://github.com/gazeciarz/Spring-AOP/tree/master/hibernateJPA

Comment: Try doing a `mvn clean package`. I sometimes find you need to do a `clean` for some of these changes to take effect.

Comment: I still got same fail.

Comment: You've got me stumped then. Perhaps something wrong with the xml config.

Comment: I think it is dependencies problem.. But I did not find any information which versions of spring-data-jpa I should use with springframework 4.2.0.RELEASE